# RecycleView and ViewModels for its items

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Google introduced the new architecture components, with ViewModels, LiveData and so on.

I try to put RecycleView items and new ViewModel together **without using DataBinding**.

Actually I do have very simple thing and have kind of algorithm for this in my mind, but no idea how to implement it.

Every RecyclerView item contain an expandable list. So if user click
   show more / show less button the visibility of the inner list should
   be toggled.

My idea:

- I need to inject a ViewModel in the ViewHolder of every item.
- I would subscribe for LiveData-Changes about visibility of the inner list.
- On show more / less clicks I would call viewModel.showMoreClicked and
  change the visibility.

Maybe you have a link or right solution (and solution without databinding).

I can also imagine, my approach is wrong.

Comment: I have an example application about architecture components. It's not exactly what do you want to do but you can check. https://github.com/volkansahin45/Moneycim